# How to join two tables A and B and have the most recent status from B?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables: A and B

A

| provider_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | date |
| 222 | date |
| 333 | date |

B

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | initialized | date |
| 111 | released | date |
| 222 | failed | date |

The result I want

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | released | A date |
| 222 | failed | A date |
| 333 | null | A date |

Among the things I tried is the left join

```
select * 
from "A" 
  left join "B" on "B"."provider_id" = "A"."provider_id" 
order by "A"."date" desc;
```

But I got the duplicated records based on `status`

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | initialized | date |
| 111 | released | date |
| 222 | failed | date |
| 333 | null | date |

Comment: Use LATERAL JOIN with according ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **many** possible ways.

The best (fastest) solutions heavily depends on exact table definitions, typical queries (what do you need *exactly*? which columns? all or few rows? filtered how? ordered how? ...), db resources, version of Postgres, indexes, and last but not least, cardinalities and data distribution.

**Assuming** you want all rows, from big tables with all columns `NOT NULL`,  referential integrity not enforced with a FK constraint, **few duplicates** in `B (provider_id)`, only plain B-tree indexes on `(provider_id)`, and the result shall be ordered by `provider_id`, this would be my query:

```
SELECT a.provider_id, b.status, a.date
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (provider_id)
          provider_id, status
   FROM   b
   ORDER  BY provider_id, date DESC
   ) b USING (provider_id)
ORDER  BY provider_id;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

It *works* in any case, but there may be (much) faster queries for other cases ...